# dependent probabilities

Tags: probability

The probability of getting a cat in any one year is 3/15. Find the probability of getting three cats in a year if:

a) the event of getting a cat is fully independent

b) the event of getting a cat is fully dependent

I get a) as $(3/15)^3$ however, for b I did not think we had enough information. The answer is $(3/15) / 3 = 1/15$. Does anyone see how they got to the answer?

Comment: Does your book give a definition of "fully dependent"?

Comment: @quasi - no, I just assumed dependent as usual.

Comment: What book is the problem from?

Comment: It's from my class, no particular book

Comment: When a problem states that events are _dependent_, it needs to specify the nature of the dependence. Without that, there's not enough information. I'm not aware of the term "fully dependent", so you would need a source for that definition (e.g., a book, your notes, the teacher).

Comment: @quasi I have checked - the term fully dependent means that if one event happens, then all events must happen. So in this context it means, if I buy one cat, then I must buy 3, so they are all dependent

Comment: Are you certain of that definition? I have never heard a term "fully dependent". If two events are dependent, the occurrence of one influences the probability of the other, but the relation needs to be specified. If indeed we'd take that definition of "fully dependent", then the chance of getting a first cat is $3/15$, but given you got a first cat the probability of getting another would be $1$, and therefore the probability of getting at least $3$ cats is $3/15$. In fact the probability of getting an infinite number of cats is $3/15$, while the probability of getting exactly $3$ is $0$...